# Fetch image variable and display on input file

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update an image and other data in a database, but when I update only text data, the image value becomes null or empty.

```
<form action="/admin/settings/why-us/update/{{$data->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
@csrf
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{$data->title}}">
<input type="file" class="form-control" value="{{$data->image}}" name="image">
<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success py-2 px-4 text-white">Update changes</button>
</form>
```

This a controller

```
public function updateWhyusPageSetting(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $title = $request->input('title');
        $image =  $image = $request->file('image');
        dd($image);

          if($request->hasFile('image')) {
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(public_path('/frontend/images/'), $filename);
                $image_upload = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            }


          DB::table('features')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update([
                'title'  => $title, 
                'image' => $image_upload
            ]);
   
 
        

        \Session::flash('flash_message', __('Why us data updated'));
        \Session::flash('flash_type', 'success');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

When I input only the title, left out the image, and tried to dump using dd($image);, I got a null value.

When updating the image, it's getting updated very well database.

Now, my question is, how do I make sure the value is captured in the input file `<input type="file" class="form-control" value="{{$data->image}}" name="image">` so that when I update other data, it also sends the image value. NB: **value="{{$data->image}}"** IS NOT capturing the data from database

Comment: Well you simply cannot. Its not possible to set a value to a file input. The value only gets set by user input. You can add a hidden field with the current image, and a checkbox to remove the image.

Comment: @GertB. Thanks for the answer. How do I make it not null?

Comment: If the user does not input a file, it will be null. handle that in the controller. Add a checkbox to remove the image if it must be possible to delete the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
public function updateWhyusPageSetting(Request $request,$id){
   $data = [];
   $data['title'] = $request->input('title');
   if($request->hasFile('image')) {
       $image = $request->file('image');
       $image->move(public_path('/frontend/images/'),$imageName = $image->hashName()); //hashName() will generate image name with extension
       $data['image'] = $imageName; // here if user uploads an image, it will add to data array then add to DB.
   }

    DB::table('features')
       ->where('id', $id)
       ->update($data); // if a user uploaded an image will add. if not, a previous image will not change
    \Session::flash('flash_message', __('Why us data updated'));
    \Session::flash('flash_type', 'success');

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Please note you should delete the old images if you don't need anymore

you can use this to delete an old image if you want

```
(new Filesystem())->delete("full/path/with/image/name.jpg");
```

Comment: The question is "how can i add a value to a file input".

Comment: description "I am trying to update an image and other data in a database, but when I update only text data, the image value becomes null or empty."

Comment: Oh, I missed that you changed the $data variable to make sure it does not set it as null. Please explain what you've changed to improve your question.

Comment: @Mohamed Gamal Eldin if Op update only text then the old image dont get null it will shows previous updated image.

Comment: @KUMAR in this code he sets a data array without image if there is no image is selected. This way the image will not be null in the database after saving.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin Thanks you soo much its working but now When I try updating an image itself, it gives an error `$file`

Comment: @Mohamed Gamal Eldin The Op wants if text or image if any one thing or both will be taken as input then it will be updated .

Comment: @Dominic can you explain the error more? I cant see a ver called `$file` at the controller.

Comment: @KUMAR I know that. so?

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin this is an error `Undefined variable $file` , where does `$file->move(`  comes from?

Comment: SORRY!! my fault. must be `$image`