# Laravel upload photo optional

Tags: laravel, file, upload

```
    public function submitReview(Request $request){
        
        $request->validate([
            'comment'=> 'required',
            'R_Image' => 'mimes:kpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'


        ]);

        
            
        $newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . 
        $request->R_Image->extension();
        $request->R_Image->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);
    


        $UserId=Auth::id();
        $query = DB::table('review') ->insert ([

                        'User_Id'=> $UserId,
                        'P_Id'=>$request->input('productID' ),
                        'R_Rating'=>$request->input('R_Rating' ),
                        'R_Comment'=>$request->input('comment' ),
                        'R_Image'=>$newImageName,
                        "created_at" =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(), # new \Datetime()
                        "updated_at" => \Carbon\Carbon::now(), 
                    

                    ]);
        
        if ($query) {
            return back()-> with ('success' , 'Review has been successfully submitted');
        }else{
            return back() -> with ('fail' , 'Something went wrong');
        }

    }
}
```

This is my code for review. The user can upload image upon submitting the form and the image is not required which is optional. However when the user do not upload image I get the error saying "Call to a member function extension() on null". But if submit the form with the image, i got no error. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: add your image uploading code into if condition if(!empty( $request->R_Image)){
 //image upload code 
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch image variable and display on input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748841/fetch-image-variable-and-display-on-input-file)

Answer (score 0):

'R_Image' => 'mimes:`jpg`,png,jpeg|max:5048' mime type must be jpg.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function submitReview(Request $request){
        
        $request->validate([
            'comment'=> 'required'
            ]);

        $newImageName = "";

        if ($request->hasFile('R_Image')) {
            $request->validate([
            'R_Image' => 'mimes:kpg,png,jpeg|max:5048'
            ]);

            $newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . 
            $request->R_Image->extension();
            $request->R_Image->move(public_path('images'), $newImageName);
        }

        $UserId=Auth::id();
        $query = DB::table('review') ->insert ([

                        'User_Id'=> $UserId,
                        'P_Id'=>$request->input('productID' ),
                        'R_Rating'=>$request->input('R_Rating' ),
                        'R_Comment'=>$request->input('comment' ),
                        'R_Image'=>$newImageName,
                        "created_at" =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(), # new \Datetime()
                        "updated_at" => \Carbon\Carbon::now(), 
                    

                    ]);
        
        if ($query) {
            return back()-> with ('success' , 'Review has been successfully submitted');
        }else{
            return back() -> with ('fail' , 'Something went wrong');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).